# How can I farm Ultima?

Tags: final-fantasy-8

In FF VIII I want some more Ultima magic for Junctions but I've already killed Ultima Weapon. I know he (and Omega Weapon) are great places to Draw Ultima from, but neither is readily available. I'm on Disc 3 with the Ragnork, most Subquests completed. Pretty sure I've claimed all the one-shot Ultima draw points.

Where else can I farm Ultima with the least pain? I know there are Draw points on the Islands closest to Heaven and Hell but that's all I can think of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can farm the [Elnoyle](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Elnoyle) in Esthar City or [Tri-Faces](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Tri-Face) as per [this post](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/197343-final-fantasy-viii/53597187#3)

Comment: Ahah, Energy crystals, forgot about those

Comment: 8 is my favourite xD never liked 7 as much, dunno why. perhaps I'm just a Final Fantasy hipster.

Comment: Same here. Probably because I got 8 first though. I did enjoy 7, but loved 8's world, especially Esthar.

Answer (score 0):

If you get the Gilgamesh card that you can refine into 10 Holy Wars, you can easily draw 100 Ultimas for all your characters on Omega Weapon (assuming your characters can draw 9 magics at a time). Of course you will have to get to this point in the game.